# must be str, not int

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Есть код

```
n = input("n=")
lst=[2]
for i in range(3, n+1, 2):
    if (i > 10) and (i%10==5):
        continue
    for j in lst:
        if j*j-1 > i:
            lst.append(i)
            break
        if (i % j == 0):
            break
    else:
        lst.append(i)
print (lst)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/red.iguana/PycharmProjects/test/untitled/dsds.py", line 3, in <module>
>
> for i in range(3, n+1, 2):
>
> TypeError: must be str, not int

Выдает эту ошибку, помогите с программой, уверен будут еще ошибки после фикса этой. Python 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) считывает строку, а вы с этой строкой пытаетесь работать как с числом. Преобразуйте строку в число вот так `int(строка)`. То есть замените строчку

```
n = input("n=")
```

на

```
n = int(input("n="))
```

Больше ошибок вроде нету: [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kfq2NZ)